# Unicode elementwise string comparison in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unicode, python-2.x

I had a question about equality comparison with numpy and arrays of strings.
Say I define the following array:

```
x = np.array(['yes', 'no', 'maybe'])
```

Then I can test for equality with other strings and it does element wise comparison with the single string (following, I think, the broadcasting rules here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html ?):

```
'yes' == x
#op : array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)

x == 'yes'
#op : array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

However, if I compare with unicode strings I get different behaviour with element wise comparison only happening if I compare the array to the string and only a single comparison being made if I compare the string to the array.

```
x == u'yes'
#op : array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)

u'yes' == x
#op : False
```

I can't find details of this behaviour in the numpy docs and was hoping someone could explain or point me to details of why comparison with unicode strings behaves differently?

Comment: What about `u'yes' == np.array([u'yes', u'no', u'maybe'])`?

Comment: It behaves the same way for reasons @一二三 answer below explains.

_i.e.:_
`u'yes' == np.array([u'yes', u'no', u'maybe'])` returns `False` and `np.array([u'yes', u'no', u'maybe']) == u'yes'` returns `array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant piece of information is this part of the [Python's coercion rules](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules):

> For objects `x`and `y`, first `x.__op__(y)` is tried. If this is not implemented or returns `NotImplemented`, `y.__rop__(x)` is tried.

Using your numpy array `x`, when the left-hand side is a `str` (`'yes' == x`):

- `'yes'.__eq__(x)` returns `NotImplemented` and
- therefore resolves to `x.__eq__('yes')` – resulting in numpy's element-wise comparison.

However, when the left-hand side is a `unicode` (`u'yes' == x`):

- `u'yes'.__eq__(x)` simply returns `False`.

The reason for the different `__eq__` behaviours is that `str.__eq__()` simply returns `NotImplemented` if its argument is not a `str` type, whereas `unicode.__eq__()` first tries to convert its argument to a `unicode`, and only returns `NotImplemented` if that conversion fails. In this case, the numpy array is convertible to a `unicode`: `u'yes' == x` is essentially `u'yes' == unicode(x)`.